# configuration-spaces and iterated loop-spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, monoid, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

In the paper [Configuration-Spaces and Iterated Loop-Spaces. Graeme Segal](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/segal.pdf), page 213-214, it is obtained that the labelled configuration space $C_n$ is homotopy equivalent to a topological monoid $C'_n$. Let a homotopy equivalent map be $$
\phi: C_n\to C'_n.$$

On the other hand, we have the path-connected components decomposition
$$
C_n=\bigsqcup_{k\geq 0} F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k
$$
as the disjoint union of $k$-th unordered configuration spaces.
Hence $$
C'_n=\phi (C_n)=\bigsqcup_{k\geq 0}\phi(F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k)).
$$
**Question:** Does the multiplication $\mu$ of $C'_n$ given in line 1-2, page 214 of [Configuration-Spaces and Iterated Loop-Spaces. Graeme Segal](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/segal.pdf) satisfy
$$
\mu: \phi(F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k))\times \phi(F(\mathbb{R}^n,l)/\Sigma_l))\to \phi(F(\mathbb{R}^n,{k+l})/\Sigma_{k+l}))?
$$
How to verify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to think about this the other way around. By definition, $C'_n$ is the set of pairs $(c,t)$ where $c \in C_n$ is a configuration, $t \ge 0$ is a real number, and the configuration $c$ is in $(0,t) \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then there is a homotopy equivalence $\psi : C'_n \to C_n$ that simply forgets the parameter $t$ (ie. $\psi(c,t) = c$). This is easily seen to be a homotopy equivalence (it's a fibration and the fiber is contractible).

Now the product of $C'_n$ is concatenation on configurations, and addition on the parameter. So in particular, yes, the concatenation of two configurations $c \in C_{n,k}$ and $\bar{c} \in C_{n,l}$ is in $C_{n, k+l}$, directly by definition. In other words, the concatenation of a configuration with $k$ points and a configuration with $l$ points has $(k+l)$ points. It follows that the product maps $\psi^{-1}(C_{n,k}) \times \psi^{-1}(C_{n,l})$ to $\psi^{-1}(C_{n,k+l})$.